# Questions about storing data in SQL or Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I have many questions on whether to store my data into SQL or Table Storage and the best way to store them for efficiency.

Use Case:

I have around 5 million rows of objects that are currently stored in mysql database. Currently the metadata is stored only in the database. (Lat, Long, ID, Timestamp). The other 150 columns about the object that are not used much were moved into the Table Storage.

- In the table storage, should these all be stored in one row with all the 150 columns not used much in one column instead of multiple rows?

For each of these 5 million objects in the database, there are certain information about them (temperature readings, trajectories, etc). The trajectory data used to be stored in SQL (~300 rows / object) but were moved to table storage to be cost effective. Currently they are stored in the table storage in a relational manner where each row looks like (PK: ID, RK: ID-Depth-Date, X, Y, Z).

- Currently it takes time time grab many of the trajectories data. Table Storage seems to be pretty slow in our case. I want to improve the performance of the gets. Should the data be stored where each Objects has 1 row for its trajectory and all the XYZ's are stored in 1 column in a JSON format? Instead of 300 rows to get, it only needs to get 1 row.
- Is the table storage the best place to store all of this data? If I wanted to get a X,Y,Z at a certain Measured Depth, I would have to get the whole row and parse through the JSON. THis is probably a trade-off.
- Is it feasible to have the trajectory data, readings, etc in a sql database where there can be (5,000,000 x 300 rows) for the trajectory data. THere is also some information about the objects where it can be (5,000,000 x 20,000 rows). This is probably too much for a SQL database and would have to be in a Azure CLoud Storage. If so, would the JSON option be the best one? The tradeoff is that if I want a portion which is 1000 rows, I would have to get the whole table, however, isnt that faster than querying through 20,000 rows. I can probably split the data into sets of 1000 rows and use sql as a meta data for finding out which sets of data I need from the Cloud Storage.

Pretty much I'm having trouble understanding how to group data and format it into Azure Cloud Tables to be efficient and fast when grabbing data for my application.

Here's an example of my data and how I am getting it: http://pastebin.com/CAyH4kHu

Comment: You're asking for advice on using one of three database engines and types: MySQL (relational), Table Storage (key/value), and DocumentDB (document). And you're asking advice on how to layout your data rows, etc. This will yield you opinions, as there is no single right answer. So, unfortunately, this type of question doesn't fit on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm asking a general question about how large data should be stored in a azure table for efficiency. I'll disinclude the documentDB and move away from the sql database portion to move towards a question that fits SO.

Comment: It'd help to provide more context... Can you provide example data and what the read/write patterns are (e.g. top 1-3 queries)? I'd be happy to have a more in-depth discussion on this... Why so many columns - are they all populated for each row? Is this to account for variability in what fields are populated for each row? Do you have to query off those fields?

Comment: @aliuy Here's an example of my data and how I am getting it: http://pastebin.com/CAyH4kHu . I have so many extra columns because there's also of data associated with the object that doesn't seem to relate to anything else.

Comment: Interesting... here's some tips 1) Tables is a key-value store; query only on keys to avoid scans (slow). If you want to query a single entry for a given depth w/o a date, consider dropping date from your row-key 2) Take advantage of query projections to get only X, Y, Z. 3) Consider partitioning across multiple SQL DBs if performance starts to lag due to having a large dataset. 4) Take a look at DocDB if you decide you need a NoSQL store w/ more queryability (it auto-hash-indexes all attributes in a json documents).

Comment: If your access pattern requires you to read multiple rows from table storage, this is a performance bottleneck. Example, if you need to read 300 rows out of the table to get a specific data point , these are 300 round trips to the server, since table storage does not support batch reads. So I'd recommend you to design your partitions in such a way that reading data requires reading as few rows as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to table storage, you can consider using Azure SQL DB Elastic Scale to spread trajectory data (and associated object metadata) across multiple Azure SQL DBs.   This allows you to overcome capacity (and compute) limits of a single database.  You would be able to perform object-specific queries or inserts efficiently, and have options to perform queries across multiple databases -- assuming you are working with a .Net application tier.   You can find out more by looking at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-get-started/